# How to convert InputStream to RDD with Java or Kotlin, without writing the stream to disk or reading it all into local memory?

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin

I have a ZipInputStream whose contents are in ".csv" format. I need to create an RDD. My constraints are:
- I cannot write the contents of the stream to disk.
- I cannot read the entire contents of the stream into local memory.
- This must be done in Kotlin or Java. (Not Scala.)

Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark Streaming to read input stream. Here is the custom receiver for input stream

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/9624/reading-input-stream-using-spark-custom-receiver.html